# Notepad++ Regular Expression problems

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm attempting to take some of the work out of pasting in insert statements and formatting them for mysqli prepared statements.

Here's an example:

```
INSERT INTO 
products
(hash, name, description, large_img, small_img, label_img, category, small, large, small_price, large_price, best_seller, in_stock) 
VALUES 
([value-1],[value-2],[value-3],[value-4],[value-5],[value-6],[value-7],[value-8],[value-9],[value-10],[value-11],[value-12],[value-13])
```

So i tried a regex:

```
find: (\[.*)(])


replace: ?
```

but instead of replacing each `[value=*]`, it replaces all of them only stopping at the last instance of a closing bracket. why?

output:

```
INSERT INTO 
products
(id, hash, name, description, large_img, small_img, label_img, category, small, large, small_price, large_price, best_seller, in_stock) 
VALUES 
(?)
```

How can i get it to replace it right. Shouldn't my regex select everything until the first closing bracket, but why does it select everything until the last closing bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to match. Use `*?` for a non-greedy match meaning "zero or more — preferably as few as possible".

```
(\[.*?)(])
```

**Note**: There is really no need to use capturing groups since you're not referencing them in your replacement call.

```
Find: \[.*?\]
Replace: ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget `*` is greedy, it tries to matche as much as possible, use non-greedy version instead:

```
(\[.*?)(])
```